# Why do i get two colors instead of the actual turtle color?

Tags: python, python-turtle

```
from turtle import Turtle

tim = Turtle()
print(tim.color())
```

why do i get 2 colors in return?

I am expexting just the color of the turtle as string

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.color - `Return the current pencolor and the current fillcolor as a pair of color specification strings or tuples `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`color()` returns a couple. The first element is the pen color and the second one is the fill color.

You can get them separately like this:

```
from turtle import Turtle

tim = Turtle()
print(tim.color()) # ('black','black')
print(tim.pencolor()) # black
print(tim.fillcolor()) # black
```